# QueryException in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using the following bean class

```
package com.hibernatemappingfile;

import java.io.Serializable;

 import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name="SKILL_SET")

public class SkillSet implements Serializable{

  @Id
  @Column(name="ID")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  private String id;
  public String getId() {
        return id;
   }
   public void setId(String id) {
      this.id = id;
   }

   @Column(name="COMPUTER_SKILLS")
   private String computer_skills;
   @Column(name="TRAININGS_ATTENDED")
   private String trainings_attended;

   @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
   private EmployeeMaster employee;


   public EmployeeMaster getEmployee() {
        return employee;
   }
   public void setEmployee(EmployeeMaster employee) {
        this.employee = employee;
   }
   public String getComputer_skills() {
        return computer_skills;
   }
   public void setComputer_skills(String computer_skills) {
        this.computer_skills = computer_skills;
   }
   public String getTrainings_attended() {
        return trainings_attended;
   }
   public void setTrainings_attended(String trainings_attended) {
        this.trainings_attended = trainings_attended;
   }


}
```

and my hql query is

```
SELECT t1.trainings_attended,t2.workingstatus 
FROM SkillSet t1, EmployeeStatus t2,EmployeeMaster em 
WHERE t1.trainings_attended=:trainings_attended AND t1.USER_ID = t2.USER_ID
```

but i am getting the following exception

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [sdnext] in context with path [/sdnext] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: USER_ID of: com.vrnda.hibernatemappingfile.SkillSet [SELECT t1.trainings_attended,t2.workingstatus FROM com.vrnda.hibernatemappingfile.SkillSet t1, com.vrnda.hibernatemappingfile.EmployeeStatus t2,com.vrnda.hibernatemappingfile.EmployeeMaster em WHERE t1.trainings_attended=:trainings_attended AND t1.USER_ID = t2.USER_ID]] with root cause
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: USER_ID of: com.vrnda.hibernatemappingfile.SkillSet [SELECT t1.trainings_attended,t2.workingstatus FROM com.vrnda.hibernatemappingfile.SkillSet t1, com.vrnda.hibernatemappingfile.EmployeeStatus t2,com.vrnda.hibernatemappingfile.EmployeeMaster em WHERE t1.trainings_attended=:trainings_attended AND t1.USER_ID = t2.USER_ID]
```

How to get the user_id of skillset table in select statement.i have tried with t1.em.USER_ID but not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `JOIN t1.employee employee` and then you will have access to `employee.user_id`

Comment: `user_id` is a database column name. And it is not need to use a join to access an id property (but unclear, does @bajky mean `emloyee.id`?)

Comment: with employee.user_id i mean primary key of employeeMaster.